# In queue,after insertion and deletion , the deleted element also appears in Output.why?

Tags: c++, class, queue

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;    

class queue  
{
int f,r;
int a[5];

public:

 queue()
 {
    f=r=-1;
 }
```

Inserting Elements in Array

```
   void enqueu(int n)  

  {
    if(r==4)
        cout<<"Overflow"<<endl;
     else
     {
        r++;
     a[r]=n;
     }
   if(f==-1)
        f=0;
   }
```

Deleting Elements from Array

```
 void dequeu() 
       {
     if(f==-1)
        cout<<"Underflow"<<endl;

        else if(f==4)
        f=-1;

       else
      {
        cout<<"The Deleted Element is "<<a[f]<<endl;
        f++;
        }
  }
```

When i try to show elements of Array.The Element which i deleted also appears.

```
   void show()  
  // showing array elements
  {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
  }

 };

int main()

 {
  queue obj;

  int n,num;
```

I used do while here which will keep on asking whether to insert or delete.

```
   do   
   {
   cout<<"1: Insert Element In Queue"<<" 2: Delete Element "<<" 3:Press 0 to Exit<<endl;

    cin>>n;

  switch(n)  
   {
  case 1:
    {
        cout<<"Enter Element to insert"<<endl;
        cin>>num;
        obj.enqueu(num);
    break;
    }
  case 2:
    {
        obj.dequeu();
        break;
    }
  }
  }
 while(n!=0);

 obj.show();


 return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Also, in `dequeu()`, if `f==r`, remove the element and change both `f` and `r` to `-1`.

Comment: Why is your indentation so funky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enqueu()` and `dequeu()` look as though how many elements are in the container is determined by members `f` and `r`.  But your `show()` ignores them and just prints all five array elements.

Answer (score 0):

The both functions `dequeue` and `show` are wrong.

When you delete an element you should shift left all remaining elements.

So in dequeue f never can be equal to 4. It is either equal to -1 or equal to 0. So I would rewrite the function the following way:

```
 void dequeu()
 {
     if ( r == -1 )
     {
        cout<<"Underflow"<<endl;
     }
     else
     {
        cout << "The Deleted Element is " << a[f] << endl;
        for ( int i = f; i < r; i++ ) a[i] = a[i+1]; 
        if ( --r == -1 ) f = r;
     }
  }
```

Function show should output only those elements that are actual elements of the queue

```
   void show() const  
  // showing array elements
  {
    for ( int i = f; i < r + 1; i++ ) cout << a[i] << endl;
  }
```